# Scraping Data using python 3.x beautiful soup and urrllib.request

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I just started python recently and as a project ive been asked to learn how to scrape data from websites but im confused because im even newer to html, so when i am doing this in python

```
price_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'price'})
```

i dont see where the class name is shown as simply 'price' for the price of a stock on https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND.

to me, the class is defined as follows

span class="priceText__1853e8a5">2,711.66

can someone explain to me what im  missing or where my mistake is?

EDIT: ive been using this website to help, and i just copied the code across and it works, but when i inspect element to see for myself i dont see whats happening.

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific answer to your question is that you can use `class_='className'` instead of matching the tag `div`s and class `attr`s. The problem in your code is that the HTML tag class is `'priceText__1853e8a5'` not `'price'`

Since the content on the webpage that you want to scrape is not static, and instead populated by a server-side or client-side script, you must let the information populate before scraping the page. I used Selenium for this and added `time.sleep(5)` to wait 5 seconds for the information to load. Then I used `browser.page_source` to get the source for the page. Finally, I was able to get that page source into a `soup` and find the tag in the soup to pull the text from it.

As a side note, the reason I used `find_all()` instead of `find()` was because I didn't know if there would be more tags with the same class.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\selenium\\webdriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
# above is my path to chromedriver, replace it with your own.
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND')
time.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds for the page to load the js
pageSource = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
prices = soup.find_all(class_='priceText__1853e8a5')
price = prices[0].text
print(price)
```

Comment: ok that makes sense. i was confused cause on the website tutorial it searched for price, and it worked and pulled all the info, but when i looked in the inspect element, it said priceText_1853,,, rather than price